# How to name css file with hashed name, just like a js file?

Tags: webpack

In webpack, I can make bundle to be named as hash, like this:

```
output: {
    path: resolvePath('dist'),
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js'
  },
```

This generates files like:

```
34.9e884d9e0051cf81aff5.js
bundle.936eb50aa67577f751e6.js
vendors.df56297c28c1d1017f2a.js
```

But css files are not getting hashed they remain:

**bundle.css**

The problem comes when I am using caching in my server and changes are not getting applied since css files are not getting renamed.

How to tell webpack to create something like `9e884d9e0051cf81aff5.bundle.css` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're using this mini-css-extract-plugin?

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
 filename: '[contenthash].bundle.css'
}),
```